# How to get Windows User Login Status using c#?

Tags: c#, windows, windows-services, wmi

How can I get my local machine users login status. Such as Disconnect, Log off and Logged In Status. It would be preferable if I can use WMI scripts.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is taken from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2008/03/04/how-to-get-the-logged-on-user-with-wmi-vbscript.aspx)
Way to get the user who has logged on a given machine with VBScript & WMI:

```
' PARAMETERS
'
strComputer = "machineName"   ' use "." for local computer 
strUser = "domain\user" ' comment this line for current user
strPassword = "password" ' comment this line for current user

' CONSTANTS
'
wbemImpersonationLevelImpersonate = 3
wbemAuthenticationLevelPktPrivacy = 6

'=======================================================================
' MAIN
'=======================================================================

' Connect to machine
'
If Not strUser = "" Then

    ' Connect using user and password
    '
    Set objLocator = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator")
    Set objWMI = objLocator.ConnectServer _
        (strComputer, "root\cimv2", strUser, strPassword)
    objWMI.Security_.ImpersonationLevel = wbemImpersonationLevelImpersonate
    objWMI.Security_.AuthenticationLevel = wbemAuthenticationLevelPktPrivacy

Else

    ' Connect using current user
    '
    Set objWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2") 

End If

' Get OS name
'
Set colOS = objWMI.InstancesOf ("Win32_OperatingSystem")

For Each objOS in colOS
    strName = objOS.Name
Next

If Instr(strName, "Windows 2000") > 0 Then

    '-------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Code for Windows 2000
    '-------------------------------------------------------------------

    ' Get user name
    '
    Set colComputer = objWMI.ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_ComputerSystem")

    For Each objComputer in colComputer
        Wscript.Echo "User: " & objComputer.UserName
    Next

    ' ------------------------------------------------------------------

Else

    ' ------------------------------------------------------------------
    ' Code for Windows XP or later
    ' ------------------------------------------------------------------

    ' Get interactive session
    '
    Set colSessions = objWMI.ExecQuery _ 
          ("Select * from Win32_LogonSession Where LogonType = 2") 

    If colSessions.Count = 0 Then 
        ' No interactive session found
        '
        Wscript.Echo "No interactive user found" 
    Else 
        'Interactive session found
        '
        For Each objSession in colSessions 

            Set colList = objWMI.ExecQuery("Associators of " _ 
            & "{Win32_LogonSession.LogonId=" & objSession.LogonId & "} " _ 
            & "Where AssocClass=Win32_LoggedOnUser Role=Dependent" ) 

            ' Show user info
            '
            For Each objItem in colList 
                WScript.Echo "User: " & objItem.Name 
                WScript.Echo "FullName: " & objItem.FullName 
                WScript.Echo "Domain: " & objItem.Domain 
            Next 

            ' Show session start time
            '
            Wscript.Echo "Start Time: " & objSession.StartTime 
        Next 
    End If 

    ' ------------------------------------------------------------------

End If
```